# How can I find if a file exists in the Microsoft Teams (SharePoint) environment using VBA?

Tags: vba, microsoft-teams

I have created a file structure within Microsoft Teams to support a sales forecasting tool. VBA routines access and modify these files as appropriate. I would like to check if a file exists in a target directory before attempting to open it and then handle any missing files within VBA. I cannot find a way of doing something analogous to the Dir instruction, e.g.

```
If Len(Dir("c:\Filename.xlsx")) = 0 Then Msgbox "This file does NOT exist."
```

Substituting the URL returns error 52 "Bad file name". 
Opening and saving files works fine, but if the file is not present, I only get a system error which I cannot handle within my environment.

Comment: What function do you use to open the file?

Comment: Set wbMonthData = Workbooks.Open(ThisMonthPath & "SOP" & ThisMonth & ThisYear & "data.xlsx")

Comment: Could you please share complete piece of code which you are trying for search the file?

Answer (score 0):

If you [sync](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-sharepoint-and-teams-files-with-your-computer-6de9ede8-5b6e-4503-80b2-6190f3354a88) the files locally, you can go on with Dir and local path instead of url.